# How do I list enabled language extensions from within GHCI?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I know that I am able to *set* language extensions with

```
:set  -XWhateverExtension
```

but how do I *list* the extensions that are currently enabled?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
> :show language
base language is: Haskell2010
with the following modifiers:
  -XNoDatatypeContexts
  -XExplicitForAll
  -XNondecreasingIndentation
  -XPatternSignatures
  -XScopedTypeVariables
```